# Обнуление времени суток в Timestamp в рамках SQL-запроса

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как отбросить часть Timestamp-а, отвечающую за время суток, в рамках SQL-запроса?

Comment: можете объяснить с примером? немного не понятно что делать

Comment: Уже разобрался. date_trunc('day', table_name) - вот что я искал.

Comment: вроде не `table_name` а будет `field_name` ??

Answer (score 1):

Стандартно:

```
cast(datetime_col as date)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
date_trunc('day', table_name).
```